# Is there any way to execute multiple sql commands inside dbms_xmlquery.getxml or DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML(..) or other PL/SQL xml functions?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-injection, oracle19c

I found an article with example of executing dynamic PL\SQL code inside of dbms_xmlquery.getxml(..) function. This article is https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/blob/master/SQL%20Injection/OracleSQL%20Injection.md#oracle-sql-list-table .
The example like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dbms_xmlquery.getxml('declare PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; 
begin execute immediate ... end;')) results FROM dual;
```

But all my attempts to execute something except of valid "SELECT" statement are falling into error inside xlm response:

```
<ERROR>oracle.xml.sql.OracleXMLSQLException: Invalid query </ERROR>.
```

Even query like this

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dbms_xmlquery.getxml('begin execute immediate '' begin select 1 from dual; end;'' end;')) results FROM dual;
```

But query

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dbms_xmlquery.getxml('select 1 from dual')) results FROM dual;
```

works fine.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you are executing these queries, and format your code and error messages correctly.

Comment: Are you asking because you're trying to create a SQL injection test? If so, there's likely no way to run PL/SQL inside DBMS_XMLGEN - the package maybe supported that syntax a decade ago, which may have led to vulnerabilities that would explain why many hardening scripts used to revoke public access to DBMS_XMLGEN. If you're asking because you want to run multiple queries to get more results, there are at least three different ways: union all, cursor(), and select multiple rows each with a different call to GETXML.